# Sitecore 8.1 Upgrade Media section broken

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I upgraded sitecore from 7.0 to 8.1.  The only real problem I have ran into is the media section is broken and the images appear broken on the site itself.

The weird part and I can upload and download the media items.  It is broken in both chrome and firefox.

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10V8F.jpg)
Update

```
 <encodeNameReplacements>
      <replace mode="on" find="&amp;" replaceWith=",-a-," />
      <replace mode="on" find="?" replaceWith=",-q-," />
      <replace mode="on" find="/" replaceWith=",-s-," />
      <replace mode="on" find="*" replaceWith=",-w-," />
      <replace mode="on" find="." replaceWith=",-d-," />
      <replace mode="on" find=":" replaceWith=",-c-," />
    </encodeNameReplacements>
```

Comment: Do you have any additional `<encodeNameReplacements>` replacements declared in your config? If so what are they?

Comment: @jammykam see the update.

Comment: Those look fine. Have you replaced the default Media Handler with your own implementation?

Comment: Nope, its so weird cause i get file not found, but i can download via the button.

Comment: It seems like a custom implementation of a media pipeline or similar. Double check your code and config and ensure something have not been overwritten/changed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It turns out the way sitecore is configured has changed a lot between 7-8.1.  By adding

```
 <sitecore configSource="App_Config\Sitecore.config" />
```

and removing the old section fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with **Sitecore Media Protection** (included first time in Sitecore 7.5).

You can read more about it in Adam blog post ["Do not turn Sitecore Media Request protection off and protect older Sitecore versions with ImageGuard"](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2015/05/15/do-not-turn-sitecore-media-request-protection-off-and-protect-older-sitecore-versions-with-imageguard/).

But I don't know why hashes are not added to the links in Sitecore. It should be disabled for the Sitecore internal sites (e.g. `shell`, `login`, etc).

Try to disable media protection by changing the config in `/App_config/Include/Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config` file and see if this is the reason of your problems.

Comment: Hmm, set <setting name="Media.RequestProtection.Enabled" value="false" /> ?  if so its still broken. ;(  I had to add all the pipes, is there one i missed for the media section?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a replacement:

```
<replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />
```

It can cause problems in images request, if you are using spaces in media item names.
Add it to your  section

Another thing to see is if your CustomHandler section is like this:

```
<customHandlers>
   <handler trigger="-/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />
   <handler trigger="~/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />
   <handler trigger="~/api/" handler="sitecore_api.ashx" />
   <handler trigger="~/xaml/" handler="sitecore_xaml.ashx" />
   <handler trigger="~/icon/" handler="sitecore_icon.ashx" />
   <handler trigger="~/feed/" handler="sitecore_feed.ashx" />
</customHandlers>
```

This is the same of "Configuration Files Changes" especified by Sitecore Upgrade 8.1 IR

Answer (score 0):

One of the new changes in 8.1 is the change of the default prefix from "~" to "-". It could be related to this prefix change. If you take the URLs that are getting a 404 and replace the ~ with a -, do the URLs to media work?

Comment: Sadly the images are still broken after making the change.